# How to send Ajax calls to an app located in a pod in a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: ajax, docker, kubernetes

My app runs **perfectly on the localhost** of my machine. I make a number of ajax calls to my backend services. The requests I make are like the following example:

```
http.open("POST","http://127.0.0.1:3000/due",true);
```

When I put my code in docker containers and run them in my kubernetes cluster, I understand that my ajax calls wont work. What's the proper way to do the calls ?

Is there an IP that I need to send the call to? The calls are made from javascript (*front end which also runs in my cluster*) to my backend. The only solution I found is to expose my back-end services which I don't want to do.

I am not sure about how to use ClusterIP. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It can't get any more detailed than K8s docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: Use docker and put them in a network, then you can expose the container with a named endpoint

Comment: Is your backend in Kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a kubernetes [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) with the type [ClusterIP](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) targeting the backend pod. But doing so the backend will be only exposed inside the cluster. You can do it as follows.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-backend
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
  type: ClusterIP
```

After doing that you can use `http://my-backend:3000/due` to do your Ajax call. Make sure that your service in in same namespacse as your pod and to use the `selector` to point to the backend pods.

Comment: I cant' resolve the name of "my-backend" when i do an ajax call. Eventhough both my services are in the same cluster.

Comment: I suppose that you might be able to reach target `my-backend` service using DNS discovering SRV record, like `my-backend.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local`, more info [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services).

Answer (score 0):

Create a backend service that should target the backend pod. You should be hitting the backend pod using backed service dns which would look like backend-service-name. namespace. Svc. Cluster. Local

If your app is running outside the kubernetes cluster then update service type as Node Port. Then Ajax call should be hitting hostname:nodeport